# Connect a RFID Reader to Windows Tab through bluetooth

Tags: windows, tablet

We checked a RFID reader named "RF IDeas pcProx Enroll RDR-6081AKU Proximity Card Reader".It doesn't have a bluetooth facility.

I need to connect an RFID reader with my Windows tab through bluetooth.
Is any kind of RFID reader available in market?
If yes can I get source code for getting event of each RFID reading?.

Comment: It will read directly into any text control, like notepad or textbook etc..

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://solutions.filemaker.com/made-for-filemaker/detail.jsp?id=solution.10000003941

You can do a search for Bluetooth Prox Reader and find a bunch.  You need to know what card format you're going to be reading and make sure you have the appropriate reader too, but that's not what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

bluetooth rfid reader can match your computer.
maybe this bluetooth usb rfid reader can match your need.
you can refer it http://syncotek.com/product/sr_hu_601r_handheld_uhf_reader.html